# Elasticsearch: When doing an "inner_hit" on nested documents, return all fields of matched offset in the hierarchy

Tags: elasticsearch

Mapping for document:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "client_classes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "members": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "phone_nos": {
                        "type": "nested"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data in Document:

```
{
   "client_name":"client1",
   "client_classes":[
      {
         "class_name":"class1",
         "members":[
            {
               "name":"name1",
               "phone_nos":[
                  {
                     "ext":"91",
                     "number":"99119XXXX"
                  },
                  {
                     "ext":"04",
                     "number":"99885XXXX"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"name2",
               "phone_nos":[
                  {
                     "ext":"03",
                     "number":"99887XXXX"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I query for "number" with value "99119XXXX"

```
{
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"client_classes.members.phone_nos",
         "query":{
            "match":{
               "client_classes.members.phone_nos.number":"99119XXXX"
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{}
      }
   }
}
```

Result from inner hits:

```
"inner_hits":{
   "client_classes.members.phone_nos":{
      "hits":{
         "total":{
            "value":1,
            "relation":"eq"
         },
         "max_score":0.9808291,
         "hits":[
            {
               "_index":"clients",
               "_type":"_doc",
               "_id":"1",
               "_nested":{
                  "field":"client_classes",
                  "offset":0,
                  "_nested":{
                     "field":"members",
                     "offset":0,
                     "_nested":{
                        "field":"phone_nos",
                        "offset":0
                     }
                  }
               },
               "_score":0.9808291,
               "_source":{
                  "ext":"91",
                  "number":"99119XXXX"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I get the desired matched result hierarchy of all the nested objects, in the inner hit, but I only receive the "offset" value and "field" from these objects. I need the full object of the corresponding offset.

Something like this:

```
{
   "client_name":"client1",
   "client_classes":[
      {
         "class_name":"class1",
         "members":[
            {
               "name":"name1",
               "phone_nos":[
                  {
                     "ext":"91",
                     "number":"99119XXXX"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I understand that with inner_hit I also get the complete root document, from where I can use the  offset values from the innerhit object. But fetching the entire root document could be expensive for our memory, so I only need the result I have shared above.
Is there any such possibility as of now?

I am using elasticsearch 7.7

UPDATE: Added Mapping, result and a slight fix in document

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add `"_source": false` at the top-level and you'll only get the nested inner hits

```
{
   "_source": false,                 <--- add this
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"client_classes.members.phone_nos",
         "query":{
            "match":{
               "client_classes.members.phone_nos.number":"99119XXXX"
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I need source fields but only those offset objects which lead to the result (as shown in my expected result)

Comment: But that's exactly what inner_hits gives you. I'm not sure I get it...

Comment: inner_hits in my case would give me this: `{"ext":"91", "number":"99119XXXX" }` It won't give me fields from top level like members's name, although it gives me the offset number from members array. But I need the complete offset object. I know I can look up using offset values from the source object, but I then I have to load the complete source object in memory and then do a lookup for offsets. I was looking for a possibility if I could get that exact same result.

Comment: Can you share your mapping and a sample document, so I can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: sure updating my question with mapping and results. Document I have already mentioned in the first code block.

Comment: Updated with mapping and results.